# Computer hissing while switched off

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer, noise, system-sounds, defective-hardware

Apologies if this forum is not the right one but I am used to excellent advice here so here goes my question.
I have a second hand PC that is making a high pitched hissing sound even when it is switched off. The only way to stop it is to unplug or physically use the switch off button on the back. Can someone provide any advice on how to deal with this? The pitch is proper high and causing me some headaches.
Thank you,

Comment: You do not say what kind of computer, but it sounds like something in the power supply is making a noise. There is a small coil in there and that is probably the source of the noise

Comment: Replacing a power supply (PSU) in a computer is usually a fairly easy task. What make is the computer? Is there any information on the PSU near where the power cord attaches to say what make and capacity (W) it is?

Comment: Thank you for your responses guys @Andrew Morton. The machine does not have a specific make. I will check the PS details once I am near the machine. Can I ask if it could be anything else other than the power supply given these diagnostics? In other words, would electricity be reaching the motherboard (for example) and causing the hissing sound while the PC is switched off? or does the power supply prevent electricity from reaching other parts when PC is off.

Comment: @John tagging you in the comment as well :)

Comment: @Learner123 There is a +5 V standby rail which is powered all the time.

Comment: There should not be a hissing noise as you describe on the motherboard.  Not anything to hiss.

Comment: OK that seems to answer my question, as the noise is constant and does not change in pitch or frequency. Appreciated.

Comment: On a separate note,  I feel this question can be useful to many users in the future. I will add some details to the question text to make it more generalisable. Cheers.

Comment: Does the answer that it is the Power Supply (and so replace) satisfy you?

Comment: Yes- would there be other suggestions?

Comment: @Learner123 While product recommendations are off-topic, I suggest getting a gold-rated PSU. Those should be built to a good-enough quality that you won't get coil-whine or exploding capacitors. Don't skimp on the PSU.

Comment: @AndrewMorton clear. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say what kind of computer this is, but it sounds like something in the power supply is making a noise. There is a small coil in there and that is probably the source of the noise.

So at this point, I suggest you replace the power supply.